# jenkins kubernetes plugin execution issues

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am running Jenkins  on EKS with Kubernetes plugin.
I have one cloud setup, and a template running my own container image for alpine with docker ( to execute docker commands )

i have only 1 job currently that only does "docker service ls" as bash 
i get the error

> "/tmp/jenkins8475081645730667159.sh: line 2: docker: command not
>   found"

while going inside the container using exec and switching to "jenkins" user i am able to run "docker".

it looks like my pod contains both jnlp container and my alpine-docker container-when write to file , it will write it to the alpine container while if i run "docker" it will try to run it on the jnlp container, does this make any sense ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to run `docker` from your container

In your pipeline

```
      container('mycontainer') {
        sh 'docker service ls'
      }
```

You can't use a container other than the jnlp one if you are using freestyle jobs, only pipeline jobs